# Speed up numpy calculation in nested loop

Tags: python, numpy

Here're some snippet of code.

```py
def rbf(r):
    rsq = r ** 2.0
    if rsq == 0.0:
        return 0.0
    val = rsq * np.log(rsq)
    if np.isnan(val):
        return 0.0
    return val

for i in range(449):
    for j, row in enumerate(p):
        res[j] += w[i] * rbf(r=np.linalg.norm(p[i] - row))
return res
```

Here `p` represents an array with shape (4448^2, 3), `res` represents an array with shape (4448^2, ). This process of in-place addition cosumes too much time. I tried another way as following.

```py
def rbf(r):
    rsq = r ** 2.0
    if rsq == 0.0:
        return 0.0
    val = rsq * np.log(rsq)
    if np.isnan(val):
        return 0.0
    return val

def func(elem, row):
    summand = sum([w[j]
                  * rbf(r=np.linalg.norm(p[j] - row))
                  for j in range(449)])
    return summand + elem

dst_res = np.array([func(elem=elem, row=row)
                    for elem, row in zip(res, p)])
return dst_res
```

But I still failed to see any progress. Any advice for improving performance ?

Comment: What is `w`? Can you express this as a pure function with inputs (`w`, `p`?) and outputs? Why `449`? What does that have to do with `4448^2`? Please provide a proper MCVE that can be run in the terminal with no additional typing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to speed up your program.

At first I would restructure the computational function: avoid ifs or try to put them in the outermost loop, avoid computational intense functions such as power (**).

```
def rbf(r):
    #if (r==0) or (np.isinf(r)) or (np.isnan(r)):
        #return 0.0
        # NaN-Test is forwarded to the outer loop; compare computational times!
    rsq = r * r
    return rsq * np.log(rsq)
```

second: additions are comparatively fast, not much to gain by improving this. You should maybe try to vectorize your data to speed up the multiplication:

```
tmp = np.zeros(449) # store values in temporary vector 
for j, row in enumerate(p): # change order of the loop 
    for i in range(449):
        tmp[i] = rbf(r=np.linalg.norm(p[i] - row)) # fill vector
    #the NaN-Check should be actually made here: measure both scenarios
    tmp[np.isnan(tmp)] = 0.0
    
    res[j] = sum( w * tmp)
return res
```

you can reduce everything further:

```
tmp = np.zeros(449) # store values in temporary vector 
for j, row in enumerate(p): # change order of the loop 
    for i in range(449):
        tmp[i] = rbf(r=np.linalg.norm(p[i] - row)) # fill vector 
    tmp *= tmp #rbf part 1
    tmp *= np.log(tmp) # rbf part 2
    tmp[np.isnan(tmp)] = 0.0 # NaN-Testing
    
    res[j] = sum( w * tmp) #sum
return res
```

These code snippets were not testet. Further improvements possible. Always check if the answers are still correct. Please share your progress.